# How to test gradle plugin build speed impact

Tags: android, performance, gradle, gradle-plugin

I want to add new plugin to my android project, but I want to know its build speed impact.

How to test this impact correctly?

For example: I should disable caches or may be there is some instruments available for such operations

I ran build with `--no-build-cache --rerun-tasks` flags, but always get different durations. Around 2 minutes +- 20 seconds. I should probable disable incremental compilation too, but I don't know how to do it.

Comment: If you mean by "plugin" adding third party library then it seems that enough doing  sequence of "Clean Project"-"Build Project" and make build time measurement with and without "plugin". By the way, if you adding library from remote repository it will spoil the measurement with connection speed and stability. It is better to test build time with pre-downloaded jars.

Comment: @Rob no, I mean gradle plugin. like https://github.com/mannodermaus/android-junit5

Comment: I think you can make separate tasks one using plugin and other not. And measure execution time each of it with command line flag --profile. More complex way is to implement TaskExecutionListener interface. Actually it really depends on what your plugin do and it will be more clear if you describe some details in your question.

Comment: To be specific I work on a big project with 200+ modules and a lot of dependencies. We thinking about adding Junit 5 plugin, but I want to see its impact on build time. I'll try --profile flag, thanks for the suggestion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To test build speed impact you can use [gradle-profiler](https://github.com/gradle/gradle-profiler) by gradle.

It is a tool to automate the gathering of profiling and benchmarking information for Gradle builds.

It can doo all fancy statistics and other interesting things regarding profiling. You can simply launch it for any task, and it will run multiple builds and calculate avarages.

Do this without plugin in question and with it. After that, just compare the numbers.

Or you can use simpler alternative. `gradlew --profile --offline --rerun-tasks assembleFlavorDebug` then in `build/reports/profile/` you will find the report